# Codename One save photo permissions on iOS

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

I'm trying to use the share button in codename one to save a partial screenshot to the users device. After I click Share >> Save Image the app crashes (this is on an iPhone 6). On my iPhone XR when I do this it prompts me to allow my app to have access to saved photos, and works fine once I've given it permission.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can trigger looking for that permission before trying to do the share, so that it won't crash.

Comment: What OS version is the iPhone 6 running? I'm guessing that permission prompt only exists in newer versions and is crashing on an older OS so we need to add a guard against that in our code.

Comment: It's running 12.4.8

Comment: Nothing in the code pops up as particularly suspect. Can you try running with the native logging cn1lib and see if you get an error message we can work with?

Comment: Looks like this is the issue: Failed to create directory /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7522DBF-1C9D-4252-9B7E-B8BEA1B51D75/Documents/cn1storage/

Comment: Then you crashed before the actual issue was logged. Please file an issue in the issue tracker and we'll tru to reproduce it on our end